# Can't run a task file based on a condition to avoid loop on block in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-template

any hint why can't i get around running a tasks file with loop? Expanding the error output pre and post message. hope it helps

tasks

```
---
- name: Check device existence on node
  shell: "lsblk -p -l | grep {{ item.0.device }}"
  loop:  "{{ local_volume_mount_disks|subelements('partitions') }}"
  register: device_exists
  tags: debug

- name: "Run Tasks from file on condition work around to BLOCKS"
  include_tasks: device_condition_satisfied.yml
  with_items: "{{ device_exists.results }}"
  when: "item.rc == 0"
  tags: debug
```

where my include_tasks file
`device_condition_satisfied.yml` has below code task

```
- name: apt-install parted
  apt:
    name: parted=3.2*
    update_cache: yes
  with_items: "{{device_exists.results}}"
  when: "{{ item.rc }} == 1"
  tags: debug
```

output

```
ansible-playbook /ansible-managed/jenkins-slave/slave0/workspace/run_ansible_playbook@2/external_inventory-3854/playbooks/local-volume-mount.yml -i /ansible-managed/jenkins-slave/slave0/workspace/run_ansible_playbook@2/external_inventory-3854/inventory/cluster.com/hosts.ini -l node -t debug -b --become-user root --vault-password-file /ansible-managed/jenkins-slave/slave0/workspace/nvdc/run_ansible_playbook@2/-e DOCKERIO_T=****


ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
     expected <block end>, but found '?'
   
   The error appears to be in '/ansible-managed/jenkins-slave/slave0/workspace/nvdc/run_ansible_playbook@2/k8s/baremetal/roles/local_volume_mount/tasks/main.yml': line 9, column 1, but may, but may
   be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
   
   The offending line appears to be:
   
   - name: "Run Tasks from file on condition work around to BLOCKS"
     include_tasks: device_condition_satisfied.yml
   ^ here
  

 FATAL: command execution failed
   hudson.AbortException: Ansible playbook execution failed
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:262)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep$AnsiblePlaybookExecution.run(AnsiblePlaybookStep.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep$AnsiblePlaybookExecution.run(AnsiblePlaybookStep.java:321)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

ls tasks/

```
device_condition_satisfied.yml  main.yml
```

I tried follow this link [How to Loop on Block](https://ericsysmin.com/2019/06/20/how-to-loop-blocks-of-code-in-ansible/)

Comment: Can you update your question to include the content *preceding* the line in the error message?

Comment: done.. pre is just ansible run command and post is that stack trace.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense...according to the output you've shown, the error is occurring on line 52 of your file, but I don't see 52 lines in this example. What else is in that file? Or, alternately, what happens if you replace the failing task with a `debug:` task; do you still see the same error?

Comment: I was told to keep the question brief so I stripped off other tasks from my main.yaml. Posting update in error now that shows correct line number because I moved tasks related to this question to top level from `main.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here:

- You have a quoting problem. If you use any quotes within a YAML value, you need to quote the entire string. Since you have a `'` in your `name:`, you need to write:

  ```
  - name: "Run Tasks from file on condition work around to BLOCKS as we can't loop on them"
  ```
- You never nest Jinja template markers (`{{...}}`), and the value of
  `when:` is already inside an implicit Jinja context, so you would
  write:

  ```
  when: "item.rc == 0"
  ```

This may not be the entire problem, but try fixing these two issues
and, if you still see failures, update your question to include
additional details.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my results and task after incorporating your feedback and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out

I am not sure what was it but it just worked, this was a weird fix, I just had to delete the two spaces before `include_tasks` and add two spaces again back and it worked.